# Implement GZIP decompression with deflate algorithm

Tags: javascript, gzip, deflate, gunzip

I need to decompress Base64-encoded `gzip` or `deflate` data from JavaScript without adding much to the bundle size (this is why I can't just use `pako`). I found a nice, small library for decompressing `deflate` data called [`UZIP`](https://github.com/photopea/uzip.js).

It appears that `gzip` is just `deflate` with a 10-byte header and an 8-byte footer. The data is guaranteed not to not have any corruption and not have any extra headers beyond those ten bytes. With all this in mind, I assumed that I could just Base64 decode the data, convert it to a `Uint8Array`, and slice off the header and footer.

```js
const data = // some Base64-encoded, gzipped string
const dataBytes = new Uint8Array(atob(data).split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));
const decompressed = UZIP.inflate(dataBytes.slice(10, -8));
```

This code hangs indefinitely (presumably because `UZIP` has bad error handling). I tried using `pako` and `zlib` on both Node.js and the browser, but both complained about an invalid header. For reference, using `zlib.gunzip` after decoding from Base64, as well as running `pako.inflate` (which automatically detects the compression type), both properly decompress the gzipped data.

Is it possible to extract the raw `deflate` data from a gzip string? If not, are there any lightweight libraries that can decompress both `gzip` and `deflate`?

Comment: base64ing it kinda defeats the purpose of compressing it

Comment: Not my data and not my decision, I'm working on an API for a third-party endpoint. (But I totally agree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the `deflate` spec does not include headers, but `zlib` does, and many libraries call `zlib` decompression `inflate`, while calling true inflation `inflateRaw`. I changed my method calls from `inflate` to `inflateRaw` and it immediately worked.